# Subject-verb agreement

Tags: verbs

In Hans Oerberg's book *Familia Romana* you can find this sentence: *īnfrā pulmōnēs est iecur et venter* (Ch. XI; lines 20-21) - shouldn't it say "sunt iecur et venter". We have two subjects in the sentence so why is there the verb in singular?

Answer (score 7):

Because there isn't really a rule in Latin that says that the verb must necessarily be plural if there are multiple subjects (even if Allen & Greenough give [precisely such a rule](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/verbs-and-subjects)).

Now that *is* generally true if the subjects are all *persons*, so you have your *Marcus et Cornelia mortui sunt* (but: *neque Marcus neque Cornelia mortua est*). But if not, then the predicate verb *usually* agrees with the closest subject:

> In periculo castra et legiones et imperator erat. (Caes. BG 2,26,5)
> Populi provinciaeque liberatae sunt. (Cic. Phil. 5,12)

There are many exceptions. In particular, multiple thing-subjects of different genders are sometimes seen with a neutral plural predicate, so my understanding is that *infra pulmones sunt iecur et venter* would also have been correct.